# Network report integrated with Active Directory or Users

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, bandwidth, cisco-commands, netflow

How can i take network report of bandwidth consumption that integrated with AD or users?

I have ASA 5506 and configured netflow 9 with PRTG,
I can see the source IP and Destination IPs, Is there any way to see bandwidth consumption by each users?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So the trick here is tying user ID's to source IP's within your network.  If you assume that a given user's traffic all comes from their PC and, in turn, that their PC's traffic is only attributable to them then it's fairly straightforward to come up with long-term DHCP assignments and simple substitute IP's for user-id's.  Heck, at the most trivial level you could give the user PC's machine names that correspond to users and just run DNS resolution for the source IP's in your report.

Beyond the trivial case, though, it becomes a lot harder.  Dynamic IP's?  Multiple concurrent devices?  Multiple users coming from a single IP?  Application proxies on-site?  This is where it starts to get ugly and is why there isn't really a truly generalized case.  If you had some kind of ironclad way to associate user devices with login/logout - say 802.1X on both wired and wireless connections - you'd likely end up with RADIUS accounting logs that could include IP's in use, connection times, etc.  This could be correlated (via a script) with the firewall traffic logs to associate Internet bandwidth use.  It's basically something close to an ISP billing problem.

Another option might be to require users to register with the firewall before using the Internet.  This might provide a shortcut that's easier than the above - check [this article on AD and ASA single-sign on integration](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-firepower-services/200566-Configure-Active-Directory-Integration-w.html#anc19) for some ideas that might fit and be a lot cleaner than the general approaches listed above.

Answer (score -1):

The Bandwidth Management abilities helps a Service Provider to manage allocation of Bandwidth in an organised way.

Defining of Packages and Plans.
Burst Mode Management
Dynamic Package Rating
Manage and Control User Upload and Download Speed
Bandwidth Management on the basis of Days & Time